# Sending image from Nodejs to Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, file-transfer

I'm trying to send an image from the server to the client. After some googling, the best solution seems to send the data as ArrayBuffer and then convert it to Blob on FE. However, I'm not able to get the image to display on FE. Am I doing some conversions wrong that might cause the issue?

For the server code:

```
exports.getImage = async (req, res) => {

try {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/images/image.png`);
    let ab = file.buffer.slice(file.byteOffset, file.byteOffset + file.byteLength);
    return res.status(200).send(ab);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({
        code: err.errCode,
        description: 'General error'
    });
}
```

}

And on the receiving side in angular:

service.ts

```
getCustomMap(groupId: string, mapId: string): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
        return this._http
            .get(`${this._URL}/${groupId}/customMap/${mapId}`, {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            });
    }
```

image component:

```
getCustomMap() {
  this._groupManagerService.getCustomMap()
    .subscribe((imgFile: ArrayBuffer) => {
      map.file = new Blob([imgFile], { type: 'image/png' });
      map.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(map.file));
    });
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just serve the static file? Assuming you use express.js just use the static middleware? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html. Alternatively express also has a res.sendFile() method: https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: I need to check the user access first and his rights before I decide to serve the image. Thats why I chose to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply follow the steps below:

**1. Server / Node.js:**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const imageName = "image.png"
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "images", imageName);

    fs.exists(imagePath, exists => {
        if (exists) {
            const { size } = fs.statSync(imagePath);

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png',
                'Content-Length': size,
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename='${imageName}`
            });

            fs.createReadStream(imagePath).pipe(res);

        }
        else res.status(400).send('Error: Image does not exists');
    });
})
```

Optionally: using `sendFile` as below:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const imageName = "image.jpg"
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "images", imageName);

    fs.exists(imagePath, exists => {
        if (exists) res.sendFile(imagePath);
        else res.status(400).send('Error: Image does not exists');
    });
});
```

**2. Client / Angular - Component:**

```
 public url: SafeResourceUrl;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.getImage('URL').subscribe(x => this.url = x)
 }

 public getImage(url: string): Observable<SafeResourceUrl> {
   return this.http
     .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
     .pipe(
       map(x => {
         const urlToBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(x) // get a URL for the blob
         return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(urlToBlob); // tell Anuglar to trust this value
       }),
     );
 }
```

**3. Client / Angular - Template:**

```html
<img [src]="url">
```

Comment: This approach worked for me. Thanks a lot, Rafi, you are a lifesaver :)