# Express send binary buffer to Angular 9

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Good day everybody.

In my **compare2.js** (Node JS/Express service) this is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
const fs = require("fs");
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = 3001;

var imgBuffer;
let img = __dirname + "/zeb1.jpg";
fs.readFile(img,function(err,content)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log("NO image!")
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log(content);
        imgBuffer = content;
        console.log(imgBuffer);         
    }
});
app.get('/',function(req,res,next)
{
    console.log("What I am sending ",imgBuffer);
    res.status(205).send(imgBuffer).end();
});

app.listen(port,()=>
{
    console.log("server running on " + port);
});
```

The console output is :

> What I am sending <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00
> 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 09 06 07 12 12 12 15 10 12 12 15 16 10
> 15 15 0f 15 15 15 15 10 0f 10 15 0f ... 4746 more bytes>

The receiver end in Angular

```
ImageFromService()
  {
    this.appService.getImgBin().subscribe(
      res =>
      {
        //console.log(res.body);
        var myimage333 = btoa( res );
        this.myimage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + myimage333;
        console.log("the beauty: " +this.myimage," and the beast: "+ myimage333);


        var blob = new Blob([res.blob()],{type:"image/jpg"})
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event) => 
        {
          this.URL = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);


      },
      (error) => console.log("ERROR",error),
      () => console.log("Done")
      )
  }
```

Yes, I am using both methods to try to make this binary file readable in HTML, but that is not the point. the point is that this is the Console output

> the beauty: data:image/jpeg;base64,bnVsbA==  and the beast: bnVsbA==

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'blob' of null

So how is it possible that I am sending "null" if in **compare2.js** the output was fine? And how do I solve this?

Comment: I am also facing same problem. did you get any solution??

Comment: @MaTharBeevi I wrote this question a long time ago, but I am pretty sure I did find a solution on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700804/sending-image-from-nodejs-to-angular